# how do I get a value if I click on one of the divs that have been appended?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a data that will be posted to a form but there is data that I can't take how to retrieve the "excess bag amount" so I can post it?

this is my controller

```
function getAirlinesById(idAirlines) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{route('get-baggage-airlines')}}',
                data:"airlines_id="+idAirlines,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#baggageAirline").empty();
                    for(let i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                        let category = response[i].baggage.category;
                        switch(category) {
                            case 1:
                            category = "KG";
                            break;
                            case 2:
                            category = "PCS";
                            break;
                        };

                        $("#baggageAirline").append('<div class="col-3 list-baggage"><img src="{{asset("assets/image/baggage.png")}}" alt="" width="80px"><p class="baggage-amount">'+response[i].baggage.max_range+' '+category+'</p><input type="checkbox"><p class="text-center">'+response[i].currency_symbol+' '+response[i].price_in_SGD+'</p></div>');
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

I have tried to get the selected bag amount for me to post to a form, but the bag amount and price are not sent

```
$post    = array(
   "AIRLINES_ID"    =>$input['airlines'],
   "AIRLINES_NAME"  =>$input['airlinesName'],
   "AIRPORT_ID"     =>$input['departure'],
   "AIRPORT_NAME"   =>$input['departureName'],
   "FLIGHT_NO"      =>$input['code'],
   "PNR_TICKET"     =>$input['pnr_ticket'],
   "BAG_AMOUNT"     =>$input['baggage-airlines'],
   "PRICE"      =>$input['price'],
   "DEPARTURE_DATE" =>$input['date'],
   "DEPARTURE_TIME" =>$input['time'],
   "MEMBER_ID"      => $id
                );
```

this is the html form for me to post to the controller

```
<form action="{{route('book-baggage-post')}}" method="POST" id="formPostBaggage">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label for=""><p class="mb-0">Airlines</p></label>
                                <select id="airlines_id" name="airlines" onchange="getName(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-name'))" class="select2-input-custome" required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="hidden" name="airlinesName" id="airlinesName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p>Flight No</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="code" id="codeAirline" style="background-color:#dcdcdc;">
                                        <option value="disable"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-8 pl-0">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="flight_no" id="" placeholder="Flight No" style="background-color:#dcdcdc;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 clearfix">
                                <label for=""><p class="mb-0">Departure airport</p></label>
                                <select id="departure" name="departure" onchange="getNameDeparture(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-name'))" class="select2-input-custome" required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="hidden" name="departureName" id="departureName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">PNR/Ticket No</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"name="pnr_ticket"  id="" placeholder="PNR/Ticket No" style="background-color:#dcdcdc;" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p>Departure Date Time</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date" style="background-color:#dcdcdc;" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time" id="timepicker" placeholder="Time" style="background-color:#dcdcdc;" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p>Excess Bag Amount Required</p>
                                <div class="row" id="baggageAirline">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                            <br>
                                <center>
                                    <a href="{{route('passanger')}}">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-book btn-block">
                                            <p class="mb-0">NEXT</p>
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: As far as I assume that you've posted the full markup, there is nothing inside `#baggageAirline`, so there is nothing to get the value of

Comment: yes right, but the data is a lot so I want to select only 1 data to post to the form

Comment: And how should anybody else guess why this does not work while you haven't shared a working example?

Comment: Using your browser's Network Inspector you should be able to see what your AJAX request retrieves. Does it show the bag amount and price?